# adding windows.ui.xaml.Data to VS2013 Project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, ivalueconverter

I am to use I ivalueconverter interface,
however this interface is under the namespace
windows.ui.xaml.Data

I an using Visual studio 2013
but I don't under stand how I add this namespace to the project.
I define progrect as a WPF appication.
and want to add this class

Thanks for any one who helps.

Comment: That's not where it resides. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IValueConverter lives in the *System.Windows.Data* namespace of the PresentationFramework.dll in WPF.

In Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps that targets Windows 10 devices only it lives in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Data namespace. But this does not apply to Visual Studio 2013 nor WPF so try this:

```
public class MyConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //conversion logic...
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```